# Microsoft visual studio 2013 installation failing

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2013

During installation I am getting an error `Microsoft visual studio 2013 VsGraphic Helper Dependencies RC Incorrect Function` [image: Error]

I was trying to install from ISO image and using web installer as well, getting same error in both cases. I am on Windows 7 x64 Dell XPS 16 with VS 2012 installed

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Do you have VS 2012 installed on that machine? Or another version of VS?

Comment: Yes I have VS2012 installed.

Comment: Having the same issue.  This is a brand new 64-bit Dell with no VS at all installed.

Comment: Same here! Win 7 x64. VS 2010 installed.

Comment: I get the same error using en_visual_studio_ultimate_2013_x86_dvd_3009107 and win 8.1. VS 2008, 2010, and 2012 yet installed.

Comment: i have the same error "Incorrect function" when i try to install vs 2015 but after search i find the problem: the iso image is not download complete. I download again the image and works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 RTM is already available for [download](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/10/17/visual-studio-2013-released-to-web.aspx).

I didn't get any more issues during installation with this one.

Answer (score 7):

Original blog [here](http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/visual-studio-2013-ultimate-iso-download-and-offline-installation-troubleshooting-of-incorrect-function-problem/).

Running offline installer from ISO is possible, see if below solutions work or not.

- Mount the iso with any virtual cd software
- Copy the mounted content to a local folder, e.g. C:\temp\vs2013\
- Run “vs_ultimate.exe” from the local folder

[image]

-->

[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to this article, there is a bug when downloading and using the ISO image.   The web installer is preferred.  This does of course make it harder to put it on a flash drive, which is unfortunate.  Tee article is also about installing on a Windows 8.1 machine, while I'm using Windows 7 Professional.  However, I expect that the issue is the same.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe3d5411-b601-425e-bf44-8cf5cd00f7af/visual-studio-2013-setup-failed-when-installing-on-windows-81-preview?forum=vssetup

Please bear in mind that the ISO installer leaves a lot of stuff behind when it fails - you need to uninstall it all and reboot before trying the web installer.

Comment: For VS 2015 this solved my issue. Multiple install attempts from an ISO failed with the exact same error dialog the OP was seeing. Installing from the web installer fixed the issue and installed cleanly.

Comment: And it's worth repeating, Please bear in mind that the ISO installer leaves a lot of stuff behind when it fails - you need to uninstall it all and reboot before trying the web installer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
Turns out that launching the setup with admin privileges worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error using:

Windows 8.1

ISO VS 2013 ultimate

I try copy contents in local, and I get the same error.

solution:

- verify checksum of ISO. Get file again, copy to local.
- Uninstall the failed version of 2013 from control panel -> Uninstall programs
- Restart the computer
- Clean %temp%
- Mount ISO, execute as Administrator setup.exe
- Re-run the setup again

References:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe3d5411-b601-425e-bf44-8cf5cd00f7af/visual-studio-2013-setup-failed-when-installing-on-windows-81-preview?forum=vssetup

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I'd downloaded the VS2013 Ultimate ISO from MSDN on Thursday when the announcement email went out but I had errors trying to install.  I checked the SHA1 and it didn't match what is now on the site (Monday) so I downloaded the ISO again and it worked now.

I'm on Win7sp1 with vs2012 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have updated your windows. (Restart windows after update)
If you have the ISO then mount it to virtual drive and then run the installer. (Don't extract and run)

Hope above instructions will help.

Note: Follow same process for VS 2015 installation.