# Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 install The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've windows 7 professional 64-bit. I can't install vs 2013 ultimate. I installed all updates.
But I get the error in this message.

**"KB2829760 The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider."**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft visual studio 2013 installation failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116570/microsoft-visual-studio-2013-installation-failing)

Comment: I have a different problem. my problem isn't VsGraphics Helper.  @Blorgbeard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solve

1- uninstall vs 2013 and  all components

2- restart pc

3- install vs 2013 ultimate update 2 web online [vs 2013 ultimate](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs)

Comment: This worked for me with the Visual Studio Express 2013 web installer.