# Error while installing visual studio 2013 professional

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, windows-8.1

Am getting below error message while installing VS 2013 Pro,
[image]

Am have windows 8.1 pro in my machine. Anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft visual studio 2013 installation failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116570/microsoft-visual-studio-2013-installation-failing)

Comment: click on the "log file" link and share the logs.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can uninstall the crash data created when install fail, after that restart the window and then install again.